# TeXstudio Auto Preview the PDF

Tags: texstudio, editors

I really like `TeXstudio` for the vast majority of my typesetting tasks. It's very smooth and works great for large numbers of small files, which is what I deal with most of the time (quizzes, quiz solutions, and quiz study guides). However, there are several things that bug me about `TeXstudio`, and I very much hope that someone here can point me in the right direction:

1. It annoys me that when I open up a .tex file, `TeXstudio` does not automatically search for a corresponding pdf and open that up in the Preview window. Can you configure `TeXstudio` to do this?
2. Related to # 1 above, if I have several `.tex` files open simultaneously, and I switch from one .tex file to another, can I configure `TeXstudio` to switch to the corresponding pdf in the preview window at the same time?

Note: I have cross-posted this question on [Math Help Boards](http://mathhelpboards.com/latex-help-discussion-26/texstudio-auto-preview-percents-12438.html).

Comment: Well, for your first issue is strange, almost always when I reload a previous session `TeXstudio` takes few seconds and open the PDF also. For your second issue, have you ever try to use the masterfile option and synctex?

Comment: I am running TeXstudio 2.8.2 on Xubuntu 14.04. I don't know if that would make a difference. I will try googling the masterfile option and synctex. Are there other names for these concepts? Also, is it possible for you to post screenshots somewhere of your settings? I'm wondering if there's a setting somewhere that I'm missing.

Comment: @Aradnix: I tried setting the Automatically Restore Session at Next Start option, but that was totally unsuitable, because I have lots of small files I open, and not necessarily the same ones each time. Simply setting my current file as the master would be counterproductive as well, since I would be constantly changing it, and a simple F7 would display the pdf anyway. Essentially, all I want here is for an F7 to happen automatically on startup, as well as switching pdf's in the preview whenever I switch source files.

Comment: Well, actually I don't know how to achieve exactly what you want, you can read the [documentation](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html), you can also ask in the [forums](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/). In the [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Home/) you can also find interesting things. Finally, the [mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/mailman/) is also another good place for ask.

In the other hand, you can easily stablish a masterfile in `options` and in this way don't spend time traveling from a small file to the mean

Comment: For can use `synctex^` you only need to press `Ctrl`at time to do click over the pdf for go at the corresponding line of code.